# Short IF ELSE syntax in objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, syntax, if-statement

Is there any short syntax for if-else statement in objective C like PHP:

```
if($value)
return 1;
else
return 0;
```

shorter version:

```
return $value?1:0;
```

Comment: `return value?1:0;` is same as `return !!value;`

Comment: No, there is no such thing in Objective-C itself.  But Objective-C is built on C and has full access to C syntax/semantics, and the exact same syntax is present in C, C++, Java, and several other languages.  PHP no doubt got the construct from C.

Comment: FYI, the `? :`-thing is called a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

Comment: as long as the _PHP_ is based on syntax of ANSI-C-language, and the _ObjectiveC_ is a subset of the ANSI-C-language, and the ternary operator is available in ANSI-C already – this question is totally stupid and would not have deserved even a single upvote.

Comment: @holex demand my friend!

Comment: @Firdous, that 'demand' is based on that fact, where most of the developers have no idea about the languages / operating systems and they are not interested in learning more about those either – and that is really good in my view, because as long as such question can be raised and upvoted 19 times(!) by a strict developer community, none of the companies will question the professionals' rates; they simply demand them and such questions just push our hourly rate up to the sky; it is brilliant, isn't it? :)

Comment: @holex so how many hourly rate u managed to get after this question? :)

Comment: @Firdous, here I'm doing it for fun and free; contact me in private if you have a particular task to commit it and I will tell my rate to you. ;)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Yes.

There is the `Conditional (Ternary) Operator`.

Example (pseudo):

```
value = (expression) ? (if true) : (if false);
```

Based on your example (valid code):

```
int result = value ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: This makes my code so nice, tidy and sophisticated. Thanks!

Comment: I used it like this and worked perfectly:     NSString *toRet = [dataToSave writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO]? @"Yes" :  @"No";

Answer (score 13):

It's *exactly the same* in both languages, except you typically don't find `$` signs in Objective-C variable names.

```
if(value)
return 1;
else
return 0;
```

```
return value?1:0;
```

You should also keep in mind that the conditional operator `?:` isn't a shorthand for an if-else statement so much as a shorthand for a true vs false expression. See the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: ?: is available in C and kids. It means "this or that if this is false". `int i = j ?: k;` If j is 0, k will be assigned.

Comment: @atomkirk: Interesting, so it does exist outside of PHP (and works identically). I removed my erroneous statement.

Comment: The other benefit of ?: is that "value" is only evaluated once if for example you want to do something like:    

"if value return value else return nil"

Answer (score 1):

Surprised that nobody has suggested the following :

- **Long version :**

  ```
  if(value)
      return 1;
  else
      return 0;
  ```
- **Small version :**

  ```
  return value;
  ```

And if `value` isn't a `bool` variable, just cast it : `return (BOOL)value;`

Comment: That's because the latter (small version) is just wrong. For old ObjC runtimes and compilers at least. On those `BOOL` is a `typedef` on `signed char`. As such any value with a value larger than 255 with the smaller byte all zeros (such as `256`) would result in `NO`, instead of `YES`, as casting to a single-byte `signed char` would strip the higher, non-zero bits away. Do `return !!value;` instead, or `return value != NO;`. More: http://nshipster.com/bool/